# How to run python-socketio in Thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, socket.io

I have python-socketio used in Flask and want to start `Thread` instance and emit signals from it when signal comes. In flask app I have:

```
import threading

def game(my_sio):
  my_sio.emit('log', data = "Game started!")
  return

@sio.on('start')
def startGame(sid):
  t = threading.Thread(target = game, args = [sio])
  t.start()
```

There's a simple example and it does not work. In server log I get:

`engineio:a16afb90de2e44ab8a836498086c88f6: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["log","Game started!"]`

But client never gets it!

Javascript:

```
socket.on('log', function(a) {
  console.log(a);
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So what worked for me was switching to threading mode in Flask + python-socketio as documented here:
https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html#standard-threads

I was using `eventlet` before and that caused the problem.

#### Another solution

Using eventlet is possible, but threads must be non-blocking and thus said, standard Threads are useless here.

Instead to create thread one has to use `socketio.Server` method `start_background_task` which takes function as an argument.

Also inside the threaded task, use `eventlet.sleep()` instead of the `time.sleep()` method.

But event that may not work without some hacks and use of `monkey_patch` coming with `eventlet`. [See more in documentation](http://eventlet.net/doc/patching.html#monkeypatching-the-standard-library). But if there are still problems, adding empty `eventlet.sleep()` in the import section right before the `monkey_patch` will do the trick. Found it somewhere on the web in a discussion.